# Validating user interaction/input with JavaScript - good approach?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a website with lots of controls (radio buttons, select, text fields, ...). I want to validate those controls, meaning that clicking on a radio button should disable another, or entering a certain amount in the text fields, should display a message and so on.

Whats a good appraoch to that? Its ok to use a framework, but I did not find a good one. It should be done with JavaScript.

What is a good approach to that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are trying the jquery validate plugin ?

Validation  client side data using javascript is Ok but i would recommend you to validate it on server side also in order to maintain  the  integrity of  data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a very good approach, as it enhances usability. But always validate everything at the server side too.

jQuery [Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) plugin is a very flexible alternative for client-sided form validation.

Comment: Can the jQuery plugin also disable/deselect controls according to some settings?